Combining generics with variadic arguments in a function
Let this be a simplified interface:
type BaseResponse<T> = {
  success: boolean;
  data?: T;
}

And let this function, which combines multiple BaseResponse objects into a single one:
zip<T1, T2>(response1: BaseResponse<T1>, response2: BaseResponse<T2>): BaseResponse<T1 & T2> {
    let success = true;
    let data: Partial<T1 & T2> = {};

    if (!response1.success) success = false;
    else data = {...data, ...response1.data};

    if (!response2.success) success = false;
    else data = {...data, ...response2.data};

    return {
        success,
        data: success ? data as any : undefined,
    };
}

This works well for 2 arguments. Would there be a way to do this for any number of arguments T1, T2, ..., TN?
Implementation wise, it would be simple I think - just use the logic in a for loop. I am curious about how the signature of the function would change to achieve this.

The call signature type and the implementation are almost independent of each other, since TypeScript cannot possibly follow the logic to verify that the implementation actually matches the call signature. Please [edit] the question to ask only about one of those. Otherwise you might get two answers: one with a good implementation and bad call signature, and one with a good call signature and bad implementation, and then what? The question is effectively two separate questions and needs more focus.

I am assuming your question is primarily about the call signature, and that you can handle the implementation yourself.
The UnionToIntersection<T> type from Transform union type to intersection type isn't quite the right solution; if any of your BaseResponse<T> inputs have a union type for T, then UnionToIntersection will intersect them erroneously.  If someone calls zip() on a BaseResponse<X | Y>, you should get a BaseResponse<X | Y> out, not BaseResponse<X & Y>.
So, for example, the desired behavior is:
declare const r0: BaseResponse<{ a: string }>;
declare const r1: BaseResponse<{ b: number }>;
declare const r2: BaseResponse<{ c: boolean }>;
declare const r3: BaseResponse<{ d: Date } | { e: HTMLElement }>;
const zipped = zip(r0, r1, r2, r3);
/* const zipped: BaseResponse<
   {a: string} & {b: number} & {c: boolean} & ({d: Date} | {e: HTMLElement})
                     still a union ----------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>*/

To get that, you should manipulate the tuple of inputs directly, and write a TupleToIntersection<T> utility type, possibly like this:
type TupleToIntersection<T extends any[]> =
    { [I in keyof T]: (x: T[I]) => void } extends 
    Record<number, (x: infer I) => void> ? I : never;

It works similarly to UnionToIntersection, putting each tuple element in a contravariant position (see Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance, Bivariance and Invariance in TypeScript) and then inferring a single type from that position, which gives you the intersection.
Then zip()'s call signature would be
declare function zip<T extends any[]>(
    ...response: { [I in keyof T]: BaseResponse<T[I]> }
): BaseResponse<TupleToIntersection<T>>;

And you can verify that it behaves as shown above.
Playground link to code

You could use UnionToIntersection utility. Further you should implement {success: false} case:
Playground
type BaseResponse<T> = {
  success: boolean;
  data?: T;
}

type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (arg: U) => any : never) extends ((arg: infer I) => void) ? I : never
type Simplify<T> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? T[K] extends (...args: infer B) => infer A ? (...args: B) => Simplify<A> : never : Simplify<T[K]>} extends infer A ? A : never;

function zip<T extends object, R extends BaseResponse<T>, const A extends R[]>(...responses: A): Simplify<UnionToIntersection<A[number]>> {

    const success = responses.every(response => response.success);

    if(!success) return {success} as any;

    const data = {};

    for(const response of responses){
        Object.assign(data, response);
    }

    return {
        success,
        data,
    } as any;
}

declare const r1: BaseResponse<Readonly<{test: 'test'}>>;
declare const r2: BaseResponse<Readonly<{test2: 2}>>;

const d = zip({success: true, data:{test: 'test'}}, {success: true, data:{test1: 1}});
/*
const d: {
    readonly success: true;
    readonly data: {
        readonly test: "test";
        readonly test1: 1;
    };
}
*/
const d2 = zip(r1, r2);
/*
const d2: {
    success: boolean;
    data?: {
        readonly test: "test";
        readonly test2: 2;
    } | undefined;
}
*/


A possible solution will be to use a union approach like
type MergeTypes<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (k: infer I) => void ? I : never;



type BaseResponse<T> = {
  success: boolean;
  data?: T;
};

function combineResponses<T extends any[]>(
  ...responses: { [K in keyof T]: BaseResponse<T[K]> }
): BaseResponse<MergeTypes<T[number]>> {
  let success = true;
  let data: Partial<MergeTypes<T[number]>> = {};

  for (const response of responses) {
    if (!response.success) {
      success = false;
    } 
    if (response.data) {
      data = { ...data, ...response.data };
    }
  }

  return {
    success,
    data: success ? (data as MergeTypes<T[number]>) : (data ? data as MergeTypes<T[number]> : undefined),
  };
}




With this you can combine different types and return it along with the base response.
An example usage can be found here

There might be a cleaner way to do it and not use a UnionToIntersection type. But this would work:
I've got the UnionToIntersection type from here: link
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (x: U) => void : never) extends (
  x: infer I
) => void
  ? I
  : never;

function zipSpread<T extends BaseResponse<any>[]>(
  ...responses: T
): BaseResponse<UnionToIntersection<T[number]['data']>> {
  // your logic goes here.
}

